# How to detect programmatically which keyboard user has set in his iPhone?

Tags: ios, swift, custom-keyboard

I want to know which keyboard type is set by a user in his iPhone if there are some custom keyboards installed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25786928/4488635

Comment: There is no way to find out which keyboard is active. All you can do is find all installed keyboards.

Comment: @SamB, How can you find out all installed keyboards?!