# TextField.inputView opens custom keyboard in app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, custom-keyboard

I am building keyboard app, and I am wondering if there is a possibility to open my custom keyboard when user pressing on textField within my app. Keyboard is built using storyboard.

I know that I can force textField to open number Pad, Phone pad and other Apple's keyboard options but can I open my own keyboard without going to settings and adding my 3rd party keyboard.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: isn't inputView property working for textfield?

Comment: It is working, and I can choose from a standard Apple keyboards like number Pad etc but how can I open automatically my own custom keyboard?

Comment: u will need to write it programmatically like: yourTextField.inpiutView = instance of keyboard view.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible, You have to add keyboard once from settings and then automatically your keyboard will pop up. 
if you really want your own keyboard without adding settings then you need to develop your own [custom inputView](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-creating-a-custom-text-input-view--mobile-15661).

Additional notes I have just go through better approach which might be helpful for you [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25786928/6339505) and about your second question to detect keyboard please [visit here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42889446/6339505)

**Note:** Apple will not allow you to forcefully active your own keyboard at anycast because of its policy violation.

Comment: Ok, then at least if I am adding keyboard in settings then can I force my in app textField to open only my keyboard instead of standard Apples keyboard and then pressing globe button until I find mine.

Comment: No, you can't do this.Current default keyboard will pop up. It may system or your own keyboard and you need to check if it is not your keyboard then show some suggestion to the users that they need to change keyboard by pressing Globe button